# PyroCMS - Pyrostreams multiple file upload on one entry

Tags: php, pyrocms

I've got the PyroStreams module for PyroCMS and made a stream called portfolio. Everything is working as expected, however it only allows to upload just one image for my file field. That is obvious, but I'd like to know if there's a way to upload multiple images for one stream entry without adding x number of extra file fields. Or do I need to code an extra field type myself to support this? Maybe someone's got it already?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me you have to create a separate database table that will hold all the images those are related to particular portfolio and the portfolio id by id by which you can fetch the images for particular record and then use any multiple image upload library like http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php to upload multiple images in the portfolio image table. Hopefully this will help you in achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a  [multi-upload files field type](https://codeigniter.pyrocms.com/store/details/multi_upload_files_field_type) available on the pyrostore.